# multithread populate listview in .net Framework 2.0 (VB.net)

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listview

i am new with multithreading in vbnet. i got this error.

> **Cross-thread operation not valid: Control 'lvSample' accessed from a thread other than the
>   thread it was created on.**

this is my code.

```
Private Sub xFormLoad(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim t As Threading.Thread
    t = New Threading.Thread(AddressOf populateLV)
    t.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub populateLV()

    Dim a As Integer = 0
    With lvSample
        a = .Width
        .View = View.Details
        .Columns.Add("Item", CInt(a * 0.33), HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("S-Item1", CInt(a * 0.33), HorizontalAlignment.Left)
        .Columns.Add("S-Item2", CInt(a * 0.33), HorizontalAlignment.Left)

        Dim iLv(99) As ListViewItem
        For b As Integer = 0 To iLv.GetUpperBound(0)
            iLv(b) = .Items.Add("Item-" & b.ToString("00"))
            iLv(b).SubItems.Add("SubItem(1)-" & b.ToString("00"))
            iLv(b).SubItems.Add("SubItem(2)-" & b.ToString("00"))
        Next
    End With

    lvSample.Items(99).Selected = True
    lvSample.Items(99).EnsureVisible()

End Sub
```

what should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cross-thread operation not valid: Control accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UI elements should be acessed only from the UI thread. So dont get the UI updated from the Worker thread, insted use the methods to send the update calls in the UI thread (`lvSample.BeginInvoke`)

More details are here

1. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc300429(en-us).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/cc300429%28en-us%29.aspx);
2. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a06c0dc2.aspx

Answer (score -3):

add this line in your code (in form_load function if you want)

```
System.Windows.Forms.ThreadExceptionDialog.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false
```

this will allow other thread to modify current thread's objects

Comment: i have tried that code but this is a large system and i know it makes hard to debug if i add that code.